# Можно ли как то провести отладку nginx?

Tags: сервер, nginx, debian, консоль, веб-сервер

Как узнать в какой директории ищет nginx сайт.
Дело в том что мой сайт выдает 404. Хочется узнать в какой директории nginx ищет сайт, возможно я напутал слегка что то, может есть возможность провести отладку?

Comment: Nginx ищет в той директории, которая указана в конфигурационном файле. Если файл не находится - посмотрите в каком `location` он должен обрабатываться и что там указано.

Comment: смотрите логи. по умолчанию: `/var/log/nginx/access.log` и `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Answer (score 1):

Если обычного лога ошибок (по умолчанию `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, или указанный в директиве `error_log` нужного блока `server`) недостаточно то можно включить отладочный лог, в нём ОЧЕНЬ много информации. В частности он бывает полезен при отладке путаницы с `location`. Что-бы включить отладочный лог нужно добавить `debug` к директиве error_log, вот так:

```
error_log /path/to/log debug;
```

Думаю нет смысла пересказывать прекрасную (да ещё и русскоязычную документацию nginx:
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/debugging_log.html

Так-же вам может быть этот раздел документации nginx:
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location